# How to convert text value into binary data in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am looking to convert text value into binary in react native code. Below code is written in java. I want similar thing in react native. Please anyone provide me the solution for binary conversion in react native.

```
    String s = "foo";
      byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
      StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
      for (byte b : bytes)
      {
         int val = b;
         for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
         {
            binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            val <<= 1;
         }
         binary.append(' ');
      }
      System.out.println("'" + s + "' to binary: " + binary);

//Output:
'foo' to binary: 01100110 01101111 01101111
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
const convertStringToBinary = (str) => str.split("").map(l => l.charCodeAt(0).toString(2)).join(" ");
```

You can test it like so:

`console.log(convertStringToBinary("foo"))`

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like the functional style ;)

Comment: This only works if the first bit is a 1.   It strips the 0 off the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Dan's example is good form, just strips the zero off the beginning if exists.  So I've taken that coded and added the following:

```
  convertStringToBinary = (str) =>
    str
      .split("")
      .map((l) => l.charCodeAt(0).toString(2))
      .join(" ");

  render() {
    let arr = this.convertStringToBinary(this.state.text).split(" ");

    return (
      <>
        {arr.map((str, i) => {
          while (str.length < 8) {
            str = "0" + str;
          }
          return str + " ";
        }).join("")}
      </>
    );
  }
```

I'm generating animation with mine inside a component, which is I'm going this route.